# How do you make all of the bricks the same direction?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

[image]

Currently, when I try to add a texture, the bricks are all facing different directions. Is there a way that I would be able to get all of the bricks to face the same direction?

Comment: please share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this shader setup:

[image]

important is, that you use UV as texture coordinate.

Then select your object, go to UV Editing, tap A on the right window to select all, then UV -> smart uv project

then you can something like this:

[image]